# MySQL RLIKE special chars escaping PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I'm trying to make a simple multi-word search using the RLIKE MySQL instruction but when you insert in the keyword chars like ")($*" I get a PDO exception and a MySQL error, for example inserting "(" I get:

> SQL error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'parentheses not balanced' from regexp

and the query is very simple:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.name RLIKE :q ORDER BY users.name LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Where `:q` is the PDO param for the search keyword. Exists in PHP a function or a PDO method for this kind of char escaping? Or if not another way for do that?

Answer (score 1):

These characters have a special meaning in a regex pattern, to write them as literal characters you must escape them with a double backslash: `\\(`, `\\)`, `\\$`  or put them in a character class: `[)]`, `[(]`, `[$]`

See a tutorial about regex to know these characters and their meaning.

If you want to escape these special characters from a php script, use the `preg_quote` function that automatically escapes these characters for your param. See the PHP manual for details.

However `preg_quote` is designed to deal with the PCRE syntax *(the regex engine used by PHP)* that is different from the one used in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer (sorry for the late in mine) I've resolved return using the normal LIKE doing a CONCATE of the three text fields and check the result with the search query after a basic escaping of the "%" and other chars that are not allowed in the strings in my site, so like: CONCATE(name, ' ', surname, ' ', username) LIKE '%test of name%', it's not very nice to see but works.